# UITableView Sections based on Core Data attribute

Tags: uitableview, core-data, attributes, nsfetchrequest

In my app, I have a UITableView that is populated by Core Data, currently a string called "name." I want to be able to divide this tableview into 3 sections, which could be named 0, 1 and 2, or 1, 2 and 3. The name doesn't really matter. I currently really don't know how to achieve this. I have a new attribute in my data model called "term" which is what I want the sections to be based off of. Is it best for this to be an integer?

I'm kind of a newbie at iOS development, so if anyone knows how do this, I would greatly appreciate it .

Here's my current code that sorts that populates the tableview with the "name" attribute.

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    //1 - Entity
    NSString *entityName = @"Task"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    //2 Request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Task.name = name"];

    // 4 - Sort
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand if you use a `NSFetchedResultsController` or not.

In the first case (you use it) you can take advantage of it setting `term` as the attribute for dividing in section. When you create a `NSFetchedResultsController` with `– initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:` you can pass`@"term"` as a parameter for `sectionNameKeyPath`.

In the second case, I really suggest to deal with a `NSFetchedResultsController`s when dealing with `UITableView`s. Setting up a  `NSFetchedResultsController` is really sample since you need to create it and pass it a `NSFetchRequest`. The one you created is ok.

For further info I suggest to read [core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) and also [NSFetchedResultsController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using NSFecthedResultsController. Thanks a ton for your input. I'll try this out.

Comment: @user1247573 You're welcome...Mark as answer if you find this correct. Cheers.